# perform segue from collection view

Tags: swift, collections, view, segue

My aim is to perform segue from collection view cells to view controller. In the next view controller I have statement

```
 let selectedCar = CarViewController()

 if selectedCar.selectedMaker == "a"
```

I know the way to perform segue with additional class, but do not know how to perform with collection view. I used indexPath with if else statements.
Segue name is "toModels"

```
class CarsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

public var selectedMaker = ""

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let mainMenu = ["a","b"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainMenu.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: mainMenu[indexPath.row])
    cell.labelCell.text = mainMenu[indexPath.row].capitalized

    return cell
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toModels", sender: selectedMaker)

    if indexPath == [0, 0]
    {
        selectedMaker = "a"
        print("a")
    }
    else if indexPath == [0, 1]
    {
        selectedMaker = "b"
        print("b")
    }
```

Comment: didSelectItemAt is working properly. I think I have problem with passing variable selectedMaker to the next View Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **EDIT**

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.item == 0
    {
        selectedMaker = "a"
        print("a")
    }
    else if indexPath.item == 1
    {
        selectedMaker = "b"
        print("b")
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toModels", sender: selectedMaker)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "toModels")
        {
            let objVC = segue.destination as! YOUR_NEXT_VIEWCONTROLLER
            objVC.strMaker = sender as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
```

> Define in YOUR_NEXT_VIEWCONTROLLER

```
public var strMaker = ""
```

Comment: didSelectItemAt is working properly. I think I have problem with passing variable selectedMaker to the next View Controller

Comment: Edited my answer hope it helps!